# like and comments on post of page/profile outside facebook

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

Writing details for everyone to understand it well -

1. I created a facebook application to generate a access token by that application id and secret key
2. I used that access token to get wall posts of ANY facebook page or profile or group using Graph API in my php website which is my aim
3. Now i want that any user can like or comment on a post of "facebook page wall posts" in my site which i showed in my site by graph api in section 2 above

I can comment on a post or like a post using Graph API call using my access token(with "publish_stream" permission) but if i try same for another user(logged in to fb) with my that access token then its not working.so it means i have to generate another access token for that user with "publish_stream" permission.Is that the way i have to do??

why i don't want it that if i write code to generate a access token with "publish_stream"  permission for any user without "permission dialog of application" to let user know that they giving that permission then it may have a big security lick if hacker gets my code, he can do anything with that access token, he can even delete all user profile posts!!!! or posts!!!!! anything on behalf of user.

so what is the best way to do comment,like on a post of any page/profile/group outside of fb(i will use ajax call for that in website outside of facebook)....

footnote: my client want it too..so seriously want to do it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly: you want to be able to do actions as any user, without requestion an access token for that user?

Comment: If that possible for security

Comment: How would it be more secure if you could make actions on behalf of users without their permission?

Comment: Ok i can follow per user access token but when user try  comments on a post of a group or someones profile its not works sometimes  though token has publish_stream permission.